# Backbone.js: how to unbind from events, on model remove

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, backbone.js

in backbone we have an app that uses an event Aggregator, located on the `window.App.Events`
now, in many views, we bind to that aggregator, and i manually wrote a destroy function on a view, which handles unbinding from that event aggregator and then removing the view. (instead of directly removing the view).

now, there were certain models where we needed this functionality as well, but i can't figure out how to tackle it.

certain models need to bind to certain events, but maybe i'm mistaken but if we delete a model from a collection it stays in memory due to these bindings to the event aggregator which are still in place.

there isn't really a remove function on a model, like a view has.
so how would i tacke this?

**EDIT**
on request, some code example.

```
App = {
    Events: _.extend({}, Backbone.Events)
};

var User = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'hide');
        App.Events.bind('burglar-enters-the-building', this.hide);
    },

    hide: function(burglarName){
        this.set({'isHidden': true});
        console.warn("%s is hiding... because %s entered the house", this.get('name'), burglarName);
    }

});

var Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: User

});

var House = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function(){
        this.set({'inhabitants': new Users()});
    },

    evacuate: function(){
        this.get('inhabitants').reset();
    }

});



$(function(){

    var myHouse = new House({});

    myHouse.get('inhabitants').reset([{id: 1, name: 'John'}, {id: 1, name: 'Jane'}]);

    console.log('currently living in the house: ', myHouse.get('inhabitants').toJSON());

    App.Events.trigger('burglar-enters-the-building', 'burglar1');

    myHouse.evacuate();

    console.log('currently living in the house: ', myHouse.get('inhabitants').toJSON());

    App.Events.trigger('burglar-enters-the-building', 'burglar2');

});​
```

view this code in action on jsFiddle (output in the console): http://jsfiddle.net/saelfaer/szvFY/1/

as you can see, i don't bind to the events on the model, but to an event aggregator.
unbinding events from the model itself, is not necessary because if it's removed nobody will ever trigger an event on it again. but the eventAggregator is always in place, for the ease of passing events through the entire app.

the code example shows, that even when they are removed from the collection, they don't live in the house anymore, but still execute the hide command when a burglar enters the house.

Comment: For a better understanding of your question would be nice to see a few lines of code with examples of how and where you `bind` the Model events that you want to `unbind` when the Model is removed. Seeing the directions of the event-binding is very important.

Comment: @Sander the problem is called Ghost views. During `model.destroy()` the view should be able to bind to `destroy` event. During which the proper events must be undelegated and then the View must be destroyed.

Comment: @Deeptechtons the ghost views are not a problem those are properly cleared, see my exanple, it isn't even working with views at this state, just models and collections, binding to an aggregator. when models are removed, they still exist (bound and executing when the event is called)

Comment: I see the binding-event direction is _Model -> Aggregator_ so there is not any reference from Aggregator to Model so you don't have any thing to clean-up after Model is removed.

Comment: Aparently the model is still bound, as you can see in he example, even though he 2 persons are removed from the users collection in the house, they still execute the hide function when the event is thrown. so clearly they are not properly remvoed... and that's what i'm trying to achieve, unbinding them from he aggregator so they free up the memory they use :)

Comment: Yes, you are right, I didn't found a solution yet but I have a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/XJBuf/) with less code that still reproduces the issue

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I see that even when the binding event direction is this way *Object1 -> listening -> Object2* it has to be removed in order to *Object1* lost any alive reference.

And seeing that listening to the Model `remove` event is not a solution due it is not called in a `Collection.reset()` call then we have two solutions:

#### 1. Overwrite normal Collection cleanUp

As [@dira sais here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874339/backbone-js-does-calling-collection-reset-removes-the-models-as-well) you can overwrite `Collection._removeReference` to make a more proper cleaning of the method.

I don't like this solutions for two reasons:

- I don't like to overwrite a method that has to call `super` after it.
- I don't like to overwrite private methods

#### 2. Over-wrapping your `Collection.reset()` calls

Wich is the opposite: instead of adding *deeper functionality*, add *upper functionality*.

Then instead of calling `Collection.reset()` directly you can call an implementation that *cleanUp* the models before been silently removed:

```
cleanUp: function( data ){
  this.each( function( model ) { model.unlink(); } );
  this.reset( data );
}
```

A sorter version of your code can looks like this:

```
AppEvents = {};
_.extend(AppEvents, Backbone.Events)

var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    AppEvents.on('my_event', this.listen, this);
  },

  listen: function(){
    console.log("%s still listening...", this.get('name'));
  },

  unlink: function(){
   AppEvents.off( null, null, this );
  }
});

var Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: User,

  cleanUp: function( data ){
    this.each( function( model ) { model.unlink(); } );
    this.reset( data );
  }
});


// testing
var users = new Users([{name: 'John'}]);
console.log('users.size: ', users.size()); // 1
AppEvents.trigger('my_event');             // John still listening...

users.cleanUp();
console.log('users.size: ', users.size()); // 0
AppEvents.trigger('my_event');             // (nothing)
```

Check [the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/3j7yS/).

## Update: Verification that the Model is removed after remove the binding-event link

First thing we verify that Object1 listening to an event in Object2 creates a link in the direction *Obect2 -> Object1*:

[image: Our object is retained]

In the above image we see as the Model (@314019) is not only retained by the `users` collection but also for the `AppEvents` object which is observing. Looks like the *event linking* for a programmer perspective is *Object that listen -> to -> Object that is listened* but in fact is completely the opposite: *Object that is listened -> to -> Object that is listening*.

Now if we use the `Collection.reset()` to empty the Collection we see as the `users` link has been removed but the `AppEvents` link remains:

[image: Our object is retained 2]

The `users` link has disappear and also the link `OurModel.collection` what I think is part of the `Collection._removeReference()` job.

When we use our `Collection.cleanUp()` method the object disappear from the memory, I can't make the `Chrome.profile` tool to explicitly telling me *the object @314019 has been removed* but I can see that **it is not anymore among the memory objects**.

Comment: beware I'm using Backbone `v0.9.2`, in your last jsFiddle was there a `v5 something` version of Backbone.

Comment: Now I'm thinking, still we are not sure the Model has been removed from the memory :)..

Comment: Just added a verification that with this approach the Model is removed from the memory.

Answer (score 1):

I think the clean references process is a tricky part of `Backbone`.

When you remove a `Model` from a `Collection` the Collection takes care to `unbind` any event on the Model that the Collection its self is binding. [Check this private Collection method](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L839-844).

Maybe you can use such a same technique in your Aggregator:

```
// ... Aggregator code
the_model.on( "remove", this.unlinkModel, this );
// ... more Aggregator code

unlinkModel: function( model ){
  model.off( null, null, this );
}
```

This is in the case the direction of the binding is *Aggregator -> Model*. If the direction is the opposite I don't think you have to make any cleaning after Model removed.

Comment: it does not seem like the model's 'remove' event is called in that many occasions, for example when you do a collection.reset() all existing models in here, are not removed... example: http://jsfiddle.net/saelfaer/szvFY/4/

Comment: @Sander you are right, my approach doesn't work in a `Collection.reset()` situation.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of wrapping `Collection`'s `reset` with `cleanUp` as fguillen suggested, I prefer extending `Collection` and overriding `reset` directly. The reason is that
`cleanUp` takes effect only in client's code, but not in library(i.e. *Backbone*)'s.
For example, `Collection.fetch` may internally call `Collection.reset`. Unless modifying the *Backbone's* source code, we cannot unbind models from events(as in `cleanUp`) after calling `Collection.fetch`.

Basically, my suggested snippet is as follows:

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        reset: function(models, options) {
            this.each(function(model) {
                model.unlink(); // same as fguillen's code
            });
            Backbone.Collection.prototype.reset.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    });
```

Later, we can create new collections based on `MyCollection`.